# Show that $\frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-x-\frac{2}{k}\log(2) \to |x|$ as $k \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Define the functions
> $$f(x) = \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-x-\frac{2}{k}\log(2), \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = |x|.
> $$
> I am interested how to show whether $f(x)$ converges to $g(x)$ when $k\to \infty$ and if $f(x)$ converges to $h(x) = x^2$ (or even a steeper curve like $x^4$?) when $k\to 0$. My hypothesis is because I have plotted the graph for different $k$ values and it seems so, but I am unsure how to prove this, and if it is indeed true.

How exactly would you show this? My first thought for the first case would be to just assume $k$ is large and try to simplify $f(x)$ to get a similar form to $g(x)$, but I'm really not sure how this would be done because of the logarithmic nature?

Likewise, to prove the second case, I cannot let $k=0$ because of division by $0$ so I feel a different technique might be needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it pointwise. Consider 3 cases seperately. Let $x>0$, let $x=0$ and let $x<0$ be fixed.

I'll just write the case $x>0$. Let $x$ be fixed.
$$|f(x)-g(x)|= \left| \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-x-\frac{2}{k}\log(2)- |x| \right|$$
Because $x$ is fixed we can found $K\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $k>K$ we have
$$\left| \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-\frac{2}{k}\log(e^{kx}) \right|=\left| \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-2x \right|<\epsilon $$.
and
$$\frac{2}{k}\log(2)<\epsilon $$
Putting this onto above equality we get
$$ \left| \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-x-\frac{2}{k}\log(2)- |x| \right| <\left| 2x-x- |x| \right|+2\epsilon=2\epsilon $$

**P.S.** So let me tell you what i try to do. I want to show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $k>K$. By showing this i can say that as $k\rightarrow \infty$ $f(x)$ converges to $g(x)$ pointwise.

Answer to your first comment is, term comes from my mind in order to use triangle inequality and it shouldn't be what you wrote. To second is yes it is false no matter what.

Finally i thought it was obvious but let me write last equation in more detail.
\begin{align}|f(x)-g(x)|&=\left| \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-x-\frac{2}{k}\log(2)- |x| \right| \\ 
 &\leq \left| \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-\frac{2}{k}\log(e^{kx}) \right| +\left| \frac{2}{k}\log(e^{kx})-x-|x| \right| +\left| \frac{2}{k}\log(2) \right| \\
&<\epsilon+0+\epsilon=2\epsilon \end{align}
first inequality follows from triangle inequality, second by choice of $k>K$.

Comment: For second case where $k\to 0$. I think it is false.

Comment: Where does the $-\frac{2}{k}log(e^{kx})$ term come from? It should be $-\frac{2}{k}log(2) - 2x$ right? Also, for the second case i made a slight typo, i mean it should converge to a polynomial function like $x^2$, but anyway from your method I think it is still false right?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f(x) = \frac{2}{k}\log(1+e^{kx})-x-\frac{2}{k}\log(2)$$

Write
$$\log(1+e^{kx})=\log(e^{kx}(1+e^{-kx}))=\log(e^{kx})+\log(1+e^{-kx})=kx+\log(1+e^{-kx})$$ Replace in $f(x)$ and assuming $x>0$, think about Taylor series

Comment: Why $x>0$? If i expand at $x=0$ then i get $\log(2)+kx/2 + (kx)^2/8 +...$, which i'm not sure how it equals $|x|$.